# Cannot update glibc on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, package-management, rpm, glibc, apr

I have CentOS 7 installed. I want to install the [APR package](https://apr.apache.org/) for Apache, and I'm told I cannot install it because it requires at least `glibc.2.14` while I have `glibc.2.12` installed. I have downloaded the `glibc.2.17.rpm` package, I then install it but it throws an error that it requires `glibc.common.2.17` to be installed.

I'm now stuck, because when I try to install `glibc.common.2.17`, it throws an error that it requires `glibc.2.17` (the package that I first wanted to install). There is a circular dependency it seems. How can I update `glibc 2.12` in CentOS 7? I'm totally confused...

Comment: Why aren't you using `yum` to update? That would automate this process for you. But if you've ran into a circular dependency you can usually add `--nodeps --force` to the end of the `rpm` command.

Comment: when I use yum update, it updates to the same version, 2.12.

Comment: That's interesting, you might check to see if there's an alternative package name. Sometimes RHEL/CentOS will have a lower version number for the regular package name and a more specific name for a later version. For example, on RHEL6 `samba` is Samba 3.5 whereas `samba4` is Samba 4.0. I don't have a RHEL/CentOS system to test with but you might do a `yum search glibc` to see if that's the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download the following 4 packages from a mirror:

1. glibc-2.17-55.el7.i686.rpm
2. glibc-2.17-55.el7.x86_64.rpm
3. glibc-common-2.17-55.el7.x86_64.rpm
4. glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7.x86_64.rpm

After doing so, issue a `rpm -ivh glibc-*`.  If that fails, download:

1. glibc-devel-2.17-55.el7.i686.rpm
2. glibc-devel-2.17-55.el7.x86_64.rpm

and reissue the command again.  After getting glibc updated, issue a `yum update` to resolve any new dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you have glibc 2.12 installed, you do NOT have CentOS7; you're on CentOS6.  While there's been a lot of grief about the locking of major/minor versions after distro release - it's for stability, testing and certification; you'll learn the value later - the version you're looking at should not exist under an up-to-date centos7.

Update your CentOS7, do a yum install of apr (apr-devel too?) and you're done.

If you DO have CentOS6, apr-1.3.9-5.el6_2.x86_64 requires glibc-2.12 .  Yum install will get you what you need here, as well.

In general

1. Don't mix RPMs from alient repositories:  you're looking for pain.
2. Don't mix RPMs from two different distro releases -- they're designed to work together, and tested so.
3. if it's suddenly hard, or there are strange messages, there's a really good chance you're doing something you should not.
4. Dependency Hell [tm] is self-inflicted.  No exceptions.

I worked at a distro; not in Support but adjacent to it.  #4 is a well-tested theory.